# Wordpress: Redirect URL Issues

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ssl, https

I understand that wordpress automatically redirects your url from non-www. to www. However, since I have strict SSL (HTTPS) enforced, it causes TWO redirects when a visitor enters "example.com" - i.e. it redirects from **"example.com" > "http.://www.example.com" > "https://www.example.com"**

Normally this isnt really a concern but when this happens, the TTFB becomes so much longer and nothing loads up except a blank screen.

Please help and advise what can be done to make it a 1 layer redirection from non-www to https://www.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue of combining something you've put in your htaccess and Wordpress's settings.

In Settings > General set both URLs to `https://www.yourdomain.com`. This should cause only one redirect, and will apply to the whole site. You shouldn't need anything else in your htaccess if this is set up.

If you need https only on certain pages, then that would need to instead be handled in htaccess or a plugin.

Comment: Hi Pants, I am already using https://www.yourdomain.com in the settings. And for .htaccess, all I have is RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https.://www.youdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: And I dont imagine having plugin such as ithemes security would have an impact?

Comment: Specifically do `https://www.` in the settings. Not having that in the settings and having your rewrite rule in htaccess is what is causing 2 redirects. iThemes also has a setting to force https, so that's another spot it could be.